# PHP: Get http status code that own script just sent out via shutdown function

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have a [shutdown function](http://php.net/register-shutdown-function) that checks to see if a redirect was just issued. From [headers_list()](http://php.net/headers-list) I can get the headers sent and see the location header. My question is how would I figure out what http_response_code was used in the [header()](http://php.net/header) function. Headers list doesn't have the response code.

Example code to play around with. I don't use redirects in the example code, otherwise it would loop. Main thing is I would like to detect a 301 vs any other kind of redirect. This would be inside drupal (via [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6) using [hook_exit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_exit/6)); but the example code below shows the issue. I have no way of knowing what status number was passed to the browser via header().

```
<?php
register_shutdown_function('test');

if (mt_rand(0, 1)) {
  header('X-test: junk 1', TRUE, 201);
}
else {
  header('X-test: junk 0', TRUE, 202);
}

exit();


function test() {
  if ($location = test_headers_contain('X-test: ')) {
    // Would like to check the status code that was sent out
    echo $location . '<br>';
    $list = headers_list();
    $txt = str_replace('    ', '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', nl2br(htmlentities(print_r($list, TRUE))));
    echo $txt;
  }
}

function test_headers_contain($text) {
  if (function_exists('headers_list')) {
    $list = headers_list();
    if (empty($list)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    foreach ($list as $header) {
      $info = stristr($header, $text);
      if ($info !== FALSE) {
        return $info;
      }
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

This code outputs this

```
X-test: junk 1
Array
(
    [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
    [1] => X-test: junk 1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Revision 302033](http://svn.php.net/viewvc?view=revision&revision=302033) added the function [`http_response_code`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/standard/head.c?view=markup#l286) in response to just the sort of [issue you describe](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52555), but I'm not certain when it will be included in a release. It's not in 5.3.4. If you have access, you could build a patched version of PHP with this function added. If not, you could request it of whoever on your host does have access.

Comment: Thanks; not the answer I was hoping for... but that's how it goes. At least the new function is in php's SVN. Code would have been for the boost module; now I hope drupal will accept my patch for drupal_goto. http://drupal.org/node/1003838